# how to print/log stack trace to a file in trace32?

Tags: debugging, arm, trace32

I am new to Trace32 and looking for a way to print/log contents of stack trace to a local file.

I have checked API's of B::Frame, but unable to find any save method for it.

Also, tried printing B::Frame which also didn't work

Please suggest how to save/print the stack frame into a local file?

Answer (score 2):

You can dump any window in TRACE32 by using the pre-command `WinPrint.` and redirecting printer output to a file with `PRinTer.FILE *.txt ASCIIE`.

So for the Frame.view window this would be the following PRACTICE script:

```
PRinTer.FILE mystack.txt ASCIIE   // Redirect printer output to file
WinPOS ,,,,,0                     // Optional: Avoid that printed window has a header
WinPrint.Frame.view               // Open Frame.view on printer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to TRACE32 via the API, then you can also use the API function T32_GetWindowContent ([api_remote.pdf](https://www.lauterbach.com/pdf/api_remote.pdf))